# When using CMakePresets.json, what is the equivalent of remotePreGenerateCommand?

Tags: visual-studio-2022, cmake-presets

I am trying to switch from `CMakeSettings.json` to `CMakePresets.json` in a Visual Studio CMake project targetting Linux.

In my current `CMakeSettings.json`, I used to activate a Conda environment before generating the CMake cache on remote systems (including WSL) with:

```
{
   ...
   "remotePreGenerateCommand": "conda activate foobar",
}
```

This conda environment provides `cmake` and all the build tools.

What would be the equivalent feature of `remotePreGenerateCommand` with `CMakePresets.json`? I could not find anything similar in the [Visual Studio Remote Settings vendor map](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/build/cmake-presets-json-reference?view=msvc-170#visual-studio-remote-settings-vendor-map).

Otherwise, with a `CMakePresets.json` based "Open Folder" solution, is there a way to set the `cmake` path in MSVC?